# Synchronize Domino to Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory, lotus-domino

How can I synchronize User and Group from Domino to Active Directory ?
Currently I synchronize the user and group but I can't set the members for each group to Active Directory group.

Here is my code :

```
ModificationItem member[] = new ModificationItem[user.length];
for (int i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
    member[i] = new ModificationItem(
    DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute(
        "member", userName));
}
ctx.modifyAttributes(groupName, member);
```

My group name is like : `cn=groupA,cn=Users,dc=filenet,dc=com`.

My member name is like : `cn=nameA,cn=users,dc=filenet,dc=com`.

when I run it I get a naming exception.

Comment: Can you give the exact error message?

Comment: here is error message : 

 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 00000525: NameErr: DSID-031A11CC, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
 ''
]; remaining name 'cn=antidatir,cn=users,dc=filenet,dc=com'

Comment: So NameNotFound and NO_OBJECT suggests that the parent of the name is missing. Are you sure the parents are accessible to you? Are you sure the case doesn't matter? e.g. you can use `cn=Users` and `cn=users`

Comment: ya i'm sure about it, because i'm using administrator user for authentication. and i already check with ldap browser that the group is there.